# Horizontally Concatenate Array of Columns with delimiter and ignore blank columns in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The shared [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dl93hMaHO2_hlo417yyeDMhmGNmCnVP1Dg_g0nJ6ps4/edit?usp=sharing) shows multiple column rows which can be individually concatenated horizontally with a comma & space between using `TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, A2:D2)`  and blank spaces are ignored. But textjoin cannot be used in Arrayformula as far as I know and I would like ot find a suitable replacement that can also be combined as a string along with other strings of information.

[image]

I want to be able to use this as an independent formula string that might be added to other strings of information. For example, `"Favorite colors: "& textjoin(", ",1,A2:D2)&"Favorite foods:"&textjoin(", ",1,E2:G2)&"...`

**Possible solutions**

May be a variant of one of the following:

1. Modifying this so it could be used w/ an array formula `JOIN("~", SPLIT(JOIN(CHAR(60000), B3:E3), CHAR(60000)))`
2. Modifying this formula works with join also `JOIN(", ",FILTER(H2:H,H2:H<>""))`
3. Using a combination of `IF(a2:A<>""` along with a regex replacement at the end (see my answer below) but this could be very long formula compared to textjoin if there are many columns)

An ideal solution would be concise and look closest to something this:

```
arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, A2:A,B2:B,C2:C)
```

Shared sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dl93hMaHO2_hlo417yyeDMhmGNmCnVP1Dg_g0nJ6ps4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:D="",,A2:D&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a series of IF statements, adding a delimiter and then removing any trailing delimiters can be accomplished using:    Arrayformula(regexreplace(if(A2:A100<>"",A2:A100&", ","")&if(B2:B100<>"",B2:B100&", ","")&if(C2:C100<>"",C2:C100&", ","")&if(D2:D100<>"",D2:D100&", ",""),", $",""))

Answer (score 0):

Use a [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465), like this:

`=transpose(query(transpose(A2:D), "", 9^9))`

The formula will separate values with spaces. To separate with commas and remove unwanted white space, use `trim()` and `substitute()` or `regexreplace()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( substitute( trim( transpose( query( transpose(A2:D), "", 9^9 ) ) ), " ", ", " ) )`

Comment: What if I wanted to add this formula to something else, to result in "Test: red, white, blue"? For example, adding if(A2:D<>"","today: ","")& results in 4 columns being populated

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).